# Yeast rinsing with store bought water?

Tags: reusing-yeast, yeast-washing

Just starting to get into yeast management and in every instance I can find describing how to rinse yeast people are boiling water, letting it cool and continuing from there. What would be the difference if I were using a store bought gallon and sanitized jars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary intent of boiling the water is to kill any bacteria or other critters that may be living in it.

If you are confident that the water you buy at the store is of the same purity, then by all means use it. If not, then you should boil the water regardless of source.

Comment: Sure would suck to have an entire batch go bad because of dirty water in the yeast rinsing.  I've never purposefully wasted yeast by trying to contaminate it during rinsing, but I'd imagine you wouldn't be able to smell any off flavors from the yeast either, so it's likely a crap-shoot until fermentation as to whether or not it's contaminated, and that's too much of a risk for me.

Comment: I taste my yeast samples before pitching them to a starter. Some yeast taste quite different than others, but if you start tasting all the time, then relate the taste to the final taste of your brew, you will begin to learn what healthy yeast should taste like. Don't drink too much though! It's active yeast!